# Is the Moment of Intertia of A Thin Rod equal to The Moment of Intertia of a thin Strip?

Tags: moment-of-inertia

**This is the Moment of Intertia of a Thin rod**

[image]

I am not aware of a formula for a thin strip (or if there is any such formula). I was imagining a thin rod does not have a radius in the formula (thin means very very small radius which is negligible).

So why isn't this formula also same for a narrow thin strip?

A narrow thin strip would mean with a **thickness and width** which is **negligible**. For me these two objects (when imagined) at this **level**, looks exactly the same (shape and size).

A rod with infinitely small radius and a narrow thin strip with Infintely small width and thickness would mean the same object (according to my imagination). Am I correct ? Or where have I gone wrong???

Also if there is a formula for the inertia of a thin strip, **Please let me know**

Also to let anyone understand my problem better-

In my exam question it says thin strip, and nowhere has it mentioned about the width of it. So what if I ask you, tell me the moment of inertia of a thin strip of length 8a  perpendicular to the strip and passing through the center.

Comment: You haven't said whether the *width* of your thin strip is also negligible.

Comment: Thickness means width. Re read my question :)

Comment: I imagine a strip as a rectangle with a large length, a small width, and a negligible thickness. Perhaps this is different from what you consider a strip.

Comment: I added thickness/width to and made negligible as bold. Also I have mentioned it for a second time in "A rod with infinitely small radius and a thin strip with Infintely small thickness..."

Comment: Oh yes your correct @Rahul , but that is what i meant , a small width means negligilbe width right? Because thats what you do in Integrating to find the moment of internia, isnt it ?

Comment: A thin rod is assumed to have a symmetrical cross section of negligible diameter. A strip sounds like a rectangle when you cut through it, as though one of the dimensions is less negligible than the other. Then it will matter which axis you take.

Comment: @Rahul , you are talking about a strip, I mentioned a thin strip, which means negligilbly thin. If a thin rod means negligible diameter, a thin strip means the same (negligble width).

Comment: @MarkBennet it is a THIN strip. Sorry , I didnt understand can you explain??

Comment: Why negative voted???? I was crystal clear with my question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling it a thin strip implies that only one of its dimensions is negligible. You still have to know the width. If it doesn't have a width, then it is not a strip - it is a rod as you suspect.

The only difference in the case of a strip versus a rod would arise when there is a rotational component about an axis parallel to the length of the strip. The strip will have a moment of inertia about that axis, 1/3 m / w<sup>2</sup>.

Edit: Here's the full derivation. We begin by looking at the case of a flat rectangle, rotating about an axis perpendicular to its plane and passing through its center.

[image: integrate to find moment of inertia]

I am not sure the best way to render my math, so I'll paste it here in my own ascii format. If this is not readable I will need to find a better rendering tool.

```
I = int[x][y] (r * rho * dx * dy)
 = int[x = -w/2..w/2]int[y = -l/2..l/2](r * rho * dx * dy)
 = int[x][y]((x^2 + y^2) * m / (w * l) * dx * dy)
 = m/(w*l) * (int [x][y]((x^2 dx dy) + int[x][y](y^2 dx dy))
 = m/(w*l) * (int [y](-w/2..w/2](x^3/3 dy) + int[x][-l/2..l/2](y^3/3 dx)
 = m/(3*w*l) * (int[y]( 2*w^3 / 8 dy) + int[x](2* l^3 / 8 dx)
 = m/(12 * w * l) * ([-l/2..l/2](w^3 * y) + [-w/2..w/2](l^3 * x))
 = m/(12 * w * l) (l * w^3 + w * l^3)
 = m/12 * (w^2 + l^2)

lim [w -> 0] I = m/12 * l^2

if l = 2L in your example

then I = m/12 * (4 * L^2) = 1/3 * m * L^2
```

which is the same as the equation for a thin rod of length 2L rotating about its center.